# Rotate annotation in Upset plot of complex heatmap package

Tags: r, complexheatmap, upsetplot

I want to show the numbers of the bars in the top annotation barplot in the Upset plot of ComplexHeatmap. However, I could only find parameters to rotate the name of the annotations, but not the annotations themselfes.

Taken from the ComplexHeatmap Documentation:

```
lt = list(set1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
          set2 = c("b", "c", "d", "e"))
x = list_to_matrix(lt, universal_set = letters)
m2 = make_comb_mat(x)
m2 = m2[comb_degree(m2) > 0]
UpSet(m2, top_annotation = upset_top_annotation(m2, add_numbers = T))
```

[image: Upset plot with rotated annotation]

Is there a way to not have the numbers rotated by 45 degrees?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by adding `numbers_rot = 0` to the `upset_top_annotation`.

```
lt = list(set1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
          set2 = c("b", "c", "d", "e"))
x = list_to_matrix(lt, universal_set = letters)
m2 = make_comb_mat(x)
m2 = m2[comb_degree(m2) > 0]
UpSet(m2, top_annotation = upset_top_annotation(m2, add_numbers = T, numbers_rot = 0))
```

This option is somewhat hidden in the documentation, as it is not a parameter for `upset_top_annotation`, but gets passed to the `anno_barplot`. You can find more options to pass by looking at `?anno_barplot`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess I didn't dig deep enough as the description of numbers_rot is not listed in the annot_barplot documentation at rdrr.io. But it does the trick!